# “StandardIn has not been redirected” C#

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, vsix

Below is my code. We get exception when we try to write to command line.

```
Process ourProc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
ourProc.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo %PATH%");
```

I added the below code to make redirect standadrd input true but still it does not worked.

```
ourProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: "We get exception". When you ask about an exception, please include as much information as possible **about the exception**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx), you must also set `UseShellExecute = false`. Also it might not work with already running processes -- it is start information that should be set *before* process is started.

Comment: Is there any other way we can RedirectStandardInput  ? For the open processes.

Comment: Enquiring minds are still searching for an answer to this problem.